# How do I "send" emails to the Sent Folder

Tags: email

We provide a web service that can email invoices and statements from our servers to our users customers. 
Our users have asked us that all emails sent from the web-service are also stored in the Sent Folder of the person using the web service.

We know the users email, and we could insist they provide us with IMAP access credentials.

What options do we have for saving emails sent by a user from our server in the Sent Mail folder of that user?

(hope that makes sense. It was pretty hard to explain)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is internal, you might be able to get an easy way out.  BCC the person that is 'sending' the email, then they can setup a rule that moves any emails sent from your web service outbound email (or however you can flag them) to move that email to whatever folder they want.

This keeps credentials out of the process and may help to keep your SMTP servers a little more stable as well for sending out these emails (not constantly having to deal with mistyped names/passwords).

Comment: It's not internal. Our users are actually from multiple companies. This is an option though.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an internal employee (s), then why not
 - add them as the addressee of the mails (to, cc or bcc)
 - add a filter that when such an email comes (from this service, to you, cc you or bcc you, as the case is) send it to the 'sent' folder?